# how to create a bitmap which is composed multiple images?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I have a few pictures, i know their position and size... How do I place my images in one ImageView? (as shown in the picture below)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two options:

1. create a relative layout, include 4 images views and set one image to each bitmap
2. that's a bit more complex, use `Bitmap.createBitmap(int width, int height, Bitmap.Config config);` to create a mutable bitmap with the size you want, create a new canvas with `new Canvas(bitmap);` to create a canvas into that bitmap, and use `canvas.drawBitmap(...)` to draw the 4 bitmaps into the final one.

Comment: The first does not fit - I need a zoom, scrolling.... you know, Second, II will try, thanks